# Node.js - No body returned for response

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios

This route is supposed to get a response from an external API, and return its body.

```
const router = require("express").Router();
import generateSudoku from '../components/sudoku_generator';

router.route('/:difficulty').get(async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const difficulty = req.params.difficulty

  generateSudoku(difficulty)
    .then(data => {
        res.json(data)
          .then('Sudoku generated.')
          .catch((err: string) => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the `generateSudoku` function:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = 'https://sugoku.herokuapp.com/board?difficulty=';

const generateSudoku = (difficulty: string) => {

      return axios.get(`${BASE_URL}${difficulty}`)
              .then(function(response){
              this.response = response.data
              return this.response
            })
            .catch (err => console.error(err));
};

export default generateSudoku;
```

The problem is that GET request to http://localhost:5000/play/easy returns no body. What could be the problem?
**Edit:**
Here is my `app.tsx` file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

require('dotenv').config();


const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//app.use(express.json);
app.use(cors())

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;

mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
  .then(console.log("Database connected."))
  .catch((err: string) => console.log("Error: " + err));

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully.")
})

const playRouter = require('./routes/play');
const recordsRouter = require('./routes/records');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users')

app.use('/play', playRouter);
app.use('/records', recordsRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server is running.");
});
```

Comment: Your body parser is set correctly on the app file?

Comment: @danibrum I believe so. Edited the question to add my app.tsx file. You can have a look.

Comment: Try moving your app.use(bodyParser.json()) before the urlencoded, like:

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

I had a similar problem once and this fixed it, hope it can be useful for you.

Comment: @danibrum Thanks, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following part seems wrong to me as commented inline below...

```
async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const difficulty = req.params.difficulty

  //no await for this promise
  generateSudoku(difficulty)
    .then(data => {
        res.json(data)
          //possible 'then' call on a non-promise
          .then('Sudoku generated.')
          .catch((err: string) => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
    })
}
```

Perhaps the implied error from calling 'then' was being swallowed before since you weren't waiting for anything from the async function. I speculate replacing all of that with this async function might give you a result...

```
async (req: any, res: any) => {
  try{
    const data = await generateSudoku(req.params.difficulty);
    res.json(data);
    return 'Sudoku generated.';
  }
  catch(err){
    res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err)
  }
}
```

Comment: This solved part of the problem. Thank you. (You have missed a parenthesis in your return statement.)

Answer (score 1):

I think `res.json` doesn't return a promise, so i guess it just silently throws an error. Besides, what should `.then('Sudoku generated')` really do?

Try removing that part and move the catch out too

```js
generateSudoku(difficulty)
    .then(data => res.json(data))
    .catch((err: string) => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
```

Or, since you use an `async`, you don't need to use `then`, you can just write it like this:

```js
try {
    const data = await generateSudoku(difficulty);
    res.json(data);
} catch(err) {
    res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err)
}
```

Comment: This did tidy up my code, thanks, but I still get "no body returned for response."